# How do i pull the address through to my output using my xslt even though the tags have the same names?

Tags: xslt

I am trying to pull through all addresses received in the import file through to my output file using my xslt.
I do manage to pull through the first set of addresses with the code i have inserted in between the address tags in the xslt.`
The second set of addresses dont pull through when using the same code that was used for the first set of addresses because the tag names are replicated.Instead it pulls through the first set of addresses again

Please could you assists me to pull through all addresses using my xslt to populate the addresses in the output?

The buyer address in the output is being populated with the address of the Seller because the tag names are the same. Im trying to reference the buyer address in the xslt to pull through under buyer in the output but only the Seller address pulls through.Im sorry but i dont have reproducible example.The Seller address pulls through correctly using this line of code  but when i used this same line of code for the buyer it does not work and just pulls the Seller address into the buyer address

---

*****This is the import file xml*****

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<UniversalInterchange xmlns:foo="http://www.foo.org/" xmlns:bar="http://www.bar.org">

<Body>
<OrgAddressGroup>
          <OrgAddress>
            <AddressType>Seller</AddressType>
            <Address1>16 Far Away Place</Address1>
            <Address2>17 Very Far Away Place</Address2>
            <CompanyName>Test 123</CompanyName>
            <City>Durban</City>
          </OrgAddress>

         <OrgAddress>
            <AddressType>Buyer</AddressType>
            <Address1>66 For Far Place</Address1>
             <Address2>77 Not So Far Place</Address2>
            <CompanyName>Test</CompanyName>
            <Fax>+31(0)123456789</Fax>
            <OrganizationCode>AAAbbbCCC</OrganizationCode>
            <Phone>+31(0)12345678</Phone>
          </OrgAddress>

           <OrgAddress>
            <AddressType>Sending</AddressType>
            <Address1>123 Blue Rock Place</Address1>
             <Address2>77 Highway Drive</Address2>
            <CompanyName>Test</CompanyName>
            <Fax>123456789</Fax>
            <OrganizationCode>AABBCC</OrganizationCode>
            <Phone>123456789</Phone>
          </OrgAddress>

   </OrgAddressGroup>



</Body>
    </UniversalInterchange>
```

---

*************This is my xslt*************

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:param name="vDate" select="xyz"/>
  <!-- This line of code and the in the orderDate tage is used to populate the date.These two line work together-->

  <xsl:template match ="/">
    <UniversalInterchange>
<Body>

    <OrgAddressGroup>

        <xsl:for-each select="UniversalInterchange/Body/OrgAddressGroup">
        <OrgAddress>
          <AddressType>Seller</AddressType>
          <Address1>
             <xsl:value-of select="OrgAddress/Address1"/>
          <!--   <xsl:value-of select="UniversalInterchange/Body/OrgAddressGroup/OrgAddress/Address1"/>-->
          </Address1>
          <Address2>
            <xsl:value-of select="OrgAddress/Address2"/>
          </Address2>
          <CompanyName></CompanyName>
          <City></City>
        </OrgAddress>

        <OrgAddress>
          <AddressType>Buyer</AddressType>
          <Address1>
            <xsl:value-of select="OrgAddress/Address1"/>
          </Address1>
          <Address2>
            <xsl:value-of select="OrgAddress/Address2"/>
          </Address2>
          <CompanyName></CompanyName>
          <Fax></Fax>
          <OrganizationCode></OrganizationCode>
          <Phone></Phone>
        </OrgAddress>

        <OrgAddress>
          <AddressType>Sending</AddressType>
          <Address1></Address1>
          <Address2></Address2>
          <CompanyName></CompanyName>
          <Fax></Fax>
          <OrganizationCode></OrganizationCode>
          <Phone></Phone>
        </OrgAddress>
       </xsl:for-each>

        </OrgAddressGroup>



</Body>
    </UniversalInterchange>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

*********** Current Output***********

```
<UniversalInterchange>
   <Body>
      <OrgAddressGroup>
         <OrgAddress>
            <AddressType>Seller</AddressType>
            <Address1>16 Far Away Place</Address1>
            <Address2>17 Very Far Away Place</Address2>
            <CompanyName/>
            <City/>
         </OrgAddress>
         <OrgAddress>
            <AddressType>Buyer</AddressType>
            <Address1>16 Far Away Place</Address1>
            <Address2>17 Very Far Away Place</Address2>
            <CompanyName/>
            <Fax/>
            <OrganizationCode/>
            <Phone/>
         </OrgAddress>
         <OrgAddress>
            <AddressType>Sending</AddressType>
            <Address1/>
            <Address2/>
            <CompanyName/>
            <Fax/>
            <OrganizationCode/>
            <Phone/>
         </OrgAddress>
      </OrgAddressGroup>
   </Body>
</UniversalInterchange>
```

---

********Required Output*********

```
     <UniversalInterchange>
   <Body>
      <OrgAddressGroup>
         <OrgAddress>
            <AddressType>Seller</AddressType>
            <Address1>16 Far Away Place</Address1>
            <Address2>17 Very Far Away Place</Address2>
            <CompanyName/>
            <City/>
         </OrgAddress>
         <OrgAddress>
            <AddressType>Buyer</AddressType>
            <Address1>66 For Far Place</Address1>
            <Address2>77 Not So Far Place</Address2>
            <CompanyName/>
            <Fax/>
            <OrganizationCode/>
            <Phone/>
         </OrgAddress>
         <OrgAddress>
            <AddressType>Sending</AddressType>
            <Address1/>123 Blue Rock Place</Address1>
            <Address2/>77 Highway Drive</Address2>
            <CompanyName/>
            <Fax/>
            <OrganizationCode/>
            <Phone/>
         </OrgAddress>
      </OrgAddressGroup>
   </Body>
</UniversalInterchange>
```

Comment: Please fix your question: your XML is incomplete, your XSLT is not (XSLT), and your output contains XSLT code.

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT 1.0. (which you are apparently using), `xsl:value-of` returns the value of the first node of the selected node-set.

If you want to process all `OrgAddress` elements, then make your `xsl:for-each` instruction select `OrgAddress` instead of its parent `OrganizationAddressGroup`.

Comment: thank you for the feedback i had tried what you had suggested with the loop but it does not seem to work.Any further ideas will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please edit your question and post a **reproducible** example - see [mcve].

Comment: the buyer address in the output is being populated with the address of the Seller because the tag names are the same.

Comment: The buyer address in the output is being populated with the address of the Seller because the tag names are the same. Im trying to reference the buyer address in the xslt  to pull through under buyer in the output but only the Seller address pulls through.Im sorry but i dont have reproducible example.The Seller address pulls through correctly using this line of code"<xsl:value-of select="OrgAddress/Address1"/>" but when  i used this same line of code for the buyer it does not work and just pulls the Seller address into the buyer address.

Comment: You are wasting your time (and mine). I will not respond until you post a reproducible example, one I can run just by copy/paste.

Comment: i apologise but i am new to this xslt and do not have a reproducible example that i can share

Comment: i have uploaded a reproducible example as requested.You can copy/paste and it will run.You can paste the xml import code and xlsx code i have provided in this online app https://www.freeformatter.com/xsl-transformer.html#ad-output

Comment: @Zack Well, that's progress. Now could you explain what exactly is the purpose of this transformation? I see no difference between the input and the required output, other than removing the values of CompanyName, City and a few other elements.

Comment: This is part of an xml message which creates an order in a system.I have provided this xml message as an import file format.So when someone populates that xml message and i import it to the system it creates an order.So when i receive the populated message i have to transform it and then import it.

Comment: I am afraid I have no idea what that means.

Comment: would you be able to assist in pulling the addresses across?

Comment: Its difficult for me to explain the entire thing but i really do need assistance with this.

Comment: I would like to help you but I don't know how, because I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish here.

Comment: I need to pull the addresses through,the seller address pulls through fine.But when trying to do the same for the buyer ,it doesnt work it just pulls the seller address again.

Comment: Run the code i have provided in the result/output i need the addresses to pull through and populate in the same way as it appears in the input file.

Comment: Why don't you just copy them? In fact, why do you need to do anything? What can't you use the original XML as it is?

Comment: I cant use this line of code for the buyer "<xsl:value-of select="OrgAddress/Address2"/>"

Comment: You are not answering my question. What changes - if any - do you want to make to the input document?

Comment: The input file that i provided is just a portion of the input file.This is the reason it looks like a copy of the output file.The only thing i need assistance with is pulling the address through to the output file using the xslt i provided,thats it

Comment: It would be a great help if you could assist me with this.